# Best practice for cache management with polymer-cli

Tags: caching, polymer, service-worker, polymer-cli

I'm using [polymer-cli](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli) to bootstrap & manage my polymer project.

I know that the best practice for cache management is to update the file names in each version, so you can set the cache to never expire.

But the polymer-cli team hasn't implemented it yet, so what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

New version of polymer is released. Install it. in the folder structure you will find **Polymer.json** file. In that you can define your entry, app-shell, lazy-loaded fragnments, and caching strategies like below.

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "src/shop-app.html",
  "fragments": [
    "src/shop-list.html",
    "src/shop-detail.html",
    "src/shop-cart.html",
    "src/shop-checkout.html",
    "src/lazy-resources.html"
  ],
  "sourceGlobs": [
   "src/**/*",
   "data/**/*",
   "images/**/*",
   "bower.json"
  ],
  "includeDependencies": [
    "manifest.json",
    "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Polymer Cli creates Serverworker file as part of build process. Service workers Caches the files listed in Polymer.json file . More on Service Workers here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers